# How I can round digit on the last column to 2 decimal after a dot using JQ?

Tags: arrays, json, csv, unix, jq

How I round digit on the last column to 2 decimal places?

I have json:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 9,
    "successful": 9,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 2.575364,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-2017-08",
        "_type": "log",
        "_id": "AV5V8l0oDDWj-VP3YnCw",
        "_score": 2.575364,
        "_source": {
          "acb": {
            "version": 1,
            "id": "7",
            "owner": "pc",
            "item": {
              "name": "Account Average Latency",
              "short_name": "Generate",
              "description": "Generate of last month"
            },
            "service": "gsm"
          },
          "@timestamp": "2017-07-31T22:00:00.000Z",
          "value": 210.08691986891395
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my-2017-08",
        "_type": "log",
        "_id": "AV5V8lbE28ShqBNuBl60",
        "_score": 2.575364,
        "_source": {
          "acb": {
            "version": 1,
            "id": "5",
            "owner": "pc",
            "item": {
              "name": "Profile Average Latency",
              "short_name": "Profile",
              "description": "Profile average latency of last month"
            },
            "service": "gsm"
          },
          "@timestamp": "2017-07-31T22:00:00.000Z",
          "value": 370.20963260148716
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I use JQ to get csv data:

```
["Name","Description","Result"],(.hits.hits[]._source | [.acb.item.name,.acb.item.description,.value])|@csv
```

I see result:

```
"Name","Description","Result"
"Account Average Latency","Generate of last month",210.08691986891395
"Profile Average Latency","Profile average latency of last month",370.20963260148716
```

I have *210.08691986891395* and *370.20963260148716* but I want **210.09** and **370.21**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass it to ***awk*** via pipeline:

```
jq -r '["Name","Description","Result"],(.hits.hits[]._source |
       [.acb.item.name,.acb.item.description,.value])|@csv' yourfile | 
       awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }NR>1{ $3=sprintf("%.2f",$3) }1'
```

The output:

```
"Name","Description","Result"
"Account Average Latency","Generate of last month",210.09
"Profile Average Latency","Profile average latency of last month",370.21
```

Answer (score 14):

Depending on your build of jq, you may have access to some [cstdlib math functions](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Math) (e.g., `sin` or `cos`). Since you're on *nix, you very likely do. In my particular build, I don't seem to have access to [`round`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/round) but perhaps you do.

```
def roundit: .*100.0|round/100.0;
["Name","Description","Result"],
(.hits.hits[]._source | [.acb.item.name, .acb.item.description, (.value|roundit)])
    | @csv
```

Fortunately, it could be implemented in terms of `floor` which I do have access to.

```
def roundit: .*100.0 + 0.5|floor/100.0;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I check this and I see an error: 
jq: error: round/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
def roundit: .*100.0 |round/100.0; ["Name","Description","Result"], (.hits.hits[]._source | [.acb.item.name, .acb.item.description, .value|roundit])| @csv                      
jq: 1 compile error

yes, I'm using linux (jq version 1.5)

Comment: Yeah, it would seem that `round` isn't available for you either. But we could implement in terms of `floor` too. Not exactly the same but would be close enough.

Comment: Per the official docs, it farms out the actual math work (including `round` and `floor`) to the OS. It's not your JQ build, but by design. I guess I never ran into this before because Bash has done what I needed until now.

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Math

Comment: @Beweeted The binary could have been built with or without math support, that's entirely possible. Though it's probably safe to assume that if you get it from official sources, it will have it.

Comment: how can we check if the OS has the math lib and access to `round` or `floor`?

Comment: 1.6 seems to add feature here, this works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59063724/1747983

Comment: @Tilo It depends on the build you get. If you're compiling from source, it's entirely dependent on what functions are available on the build machine. So try to find a built version that includes all. I think the official releases should have them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your current filter with minor reformatting:

```
  ["Name", "Description", "Result"]
, (   .hits.hits[]._source
    | [.acb.item.name, .acb.item.description, .value]
  )
| @csv
```

Here is a filter which rounds the value column.  Note we do this after the `@csv` so that we have full control over the string

```
def round:                                                # e.g.
    (split(".") + ["0"])[:2]                              # ["210","08691986891395"]
  | "\(.[1])000"[:3] as $x | [.[0], $x[:2], $x[2:3]]      # ["210","08","6"]
  | map(tonumber)                                         # [210,8,6]
  | if .[2] >  4 then .[2] = 0 | .[1] += 1 else . end     # [210,9,0]
  | if .[1] > 99 then .[1] = 0 | .[0] += 1 else . end     # [210,9,0]
  | ["\(.[0])", "00\(.[1])"[-2:]]                         # ["210","09"]
  | join(".")                                             # 210.09
;

  (   ["Name", "Description", "Result"] | @csv )
, (   .hits.hits[]._source
    | [.acb.item.name, .acb.item.description, .value]
    | @csv
    | split(",") | .[-1] |= round | join(",")
  )
```

If this filter is in `filter.jq` and the sample data is in `data.json` then the command

```
$ jq -Mr -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
"Name","Description","Result"
"Account Average Latency","Generate of last month",210.09
"Profile Average Latency","Profile average latency of last month",370.21
```