# jq | how to add two decimals correctly

Tags: decimal, jq

For data below when I try to add prebalance, amount to match with balance, why I am getting wrong sum value. How can I get the correct values.

```
{
    "prebalance": -2865.59,
    "amount": 3000.00,
    "balance": 134.41
},
{
    "prebalance": -1865.59,
    "amount": 2000.00,
    "balance": 134.41
}
]
```

JQ Play link for sample data.

https://jqplay.org/s/T4gL4kOkj7X

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can round digit on the last column to 2 decimal after a dot using JQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117049/how-i-can-round-digit-on-the-last-column-to-2-decimal-after-a-dot-using-jq)

Comment: The sum is correct, just not precise, a (general) limitation of floating-point arithmetics. You should always consider rounding, when dealing with (especially comparing to) floating-point numbers (or operations potentially producing them).

Comment: Can you help me to round it off two decimal places? i.e. 134.40999999999985 to 134.41

My number can be of any length not just 3 digits.

I have tried multiple Math options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum is correct, just not precise, a (general) limitation of floating-point arithmetics. You should always consider rounding, when dealing with (especially comparing to) floating-point numbers (or operations potentially producing them).

> Can you help me to round it off two decimal places? i.e. 134.40999999999985 to 134.41 My number can be of any length not just 3 digits.

###### Round the numbers for display:

```bash
map(
  .sum = .prebalance + .amount
  | .sum |= (. * 100 | round / 100)
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "prebalance": -2865.59,
    "amount": 3000,
    "balance": 134.41,
    "sum": 134.41
  },
  {
    "prebalance": -1865.59,
    "amount": 2000,
    "balance": 134.41,
    "sum": 134.41
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JNnVn7Lf67g)

###### Compare the absolute difference to a given epsilon for equality tests:

```bash
1e-9 as $epsilon | map(
  .sum = .prebalance + .amount
  | .equal = (.sum - .balance | fabs < $epsilon)
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "prebalance": -2865.59,
    "amount": 3000,
    "balance": 134.41,
    "sum": 134.40999999999985,
    "equal": true
  },
  {
    "prebalance": -1865.59,
    "amount": 2000,
    "balance": 134.41,
    "sum": 134.41000000000008,
    "equal": true
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/y8GotBij51o)